# How are ManagedThreadId's values determined in .NET?

Tags: c#, multithreading, variable-assignment

I'm curious about `Thread.ManagedThreadId` and its possible values (it's of type `int`)

Other than being unique, what are the rules that guide how the ID values are assigned?

Doing some rough testing, it *seems* as though:

- The values are always above 0,
- They start rather low (in the teens) and then increasing *almost* chronologically,
- As threads complete, the previous values are released - which means the assignment will jump back and forth between chronological values, and values that were released.
- The manner in which values are assigned doesn't seem to vary based on how the threads are created *(explicit thread creation, worker threads, etc.)*
- The order also looks to be dependent on how your threading is defined and how quickly they terminate *(i.e. simply defining the thread doesn't assign the id, but the actual start of the thread determines the value.)*

Beyond just my own testing, however, I was wondering if anyone had documentation on how the values are assigned?

Comment: From your (a developer's) perspective - the value is completely arbitrary.

Comment: It's `Thread.ManagedThreadId` **not** `Thread.ManagredThreadId`

Comment: Fixed my typo. Also, as the developer, I tread it arbitrarily - but I'm still interested in how the value is determined.

Comment: It's an implementation detail that can change between versions.

Comment: Have a [read](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ManagedThreadId.cs) there :)

Comment: Awesome, so this confirms values won't be negative, and it would ultimately be bounded by int.MaxValue.